# Does Xcode build CocoaPods every time I build my project?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, dependency-management

So I have a project with lots of code, and some of it part of open source projects hosted on GitHub, I'm thinking of removing that code and use CocoaPods to import and manage that code for me.

My question is, will that help with the project building time? does Xcode build the complete workspace every time I build my project?

When specifically does Xcode build the pods?

Comment: Cocoapods generates an Xcode project called `Pods` with various targets corresponding to each of the dependencies you declared. It then generates a workspace, containing the `Pods` project together with your application project.
Your project will effectively cause some of the targets in `Pods` to build. The artefacts are cached as per usual. Re-building your project a second and third times will only compile the code that's changed.

Comment: That's not entirely true. When installing pods, cocoapods adds build phases that copy the pods ressources by running
`"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh"` and `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh"` and that takes a few seconds every time. So even if it's probably nor recompiling some code, it's spending time on items that have not been modified

Comment: @Guig yes cocoapods hurts building time, we're moving to carthage soon for those reasons

Comment: Carthage is faster, but does not support all frameworks out there. I would love to convert to carthage, but some frameworks are not ready yet

Comment: @zirinisp Carthage builds dynamic frameworks which gets loaded at runtime, if the number of frameworks is more than 3 it will lead to a very slow initalization of the app. Apple doesn't recommend that.

Comment: @Mr.Me I have noticed that my app takes some time to load. I am using a lot of frameworks (~15). Do you have any way round that?

Comment: @zirinisp CocoaPods + use_frameworks!

Comment: @Mr.Me I was using Cocoapods with use_frameworks! and compile times were driving me crazy (I was getting 7-10 min, now with carthage I get a couple of seconds). I currently have left Cocoapods with only 3 frameworks that do not support Carthage and the compile time is less than 20 secs.

Comment: @zirinisp I know but you're shifting the responsibility on the user, right now I'm looking into building my own solution and maybe create static libraries instead. this should shave off compile time but I think it will make the app bigger.

Comment: @Mr.Me from my point of view carthage does that. It helps you have all frameworks up to date, builds them and all you have to do is add them to your project. The compile time that you shave (in my case, as it depend on how big the project/frameworks are) is huge. The change/build/test circle should not take more that 1 minute. With cocoa pods it was taking min 3 mins, now it is less than 30 seconds (bear in mind that i still use cocoa pods for 3 frameworks, as they do not work on carthage, so times can be decreased further)

Answer (score 3):

Pods will be recompiled:

- When you do a `pod install/update`
- When you do to a clean build

Most of the time, pods are not recompiled.

You can speedup clean build pods using:

https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary

Comment: I'm so used to cleaning + running I was getting frustrated. Then I read your answer and "lightbulb" dont clean every time haha

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problems and developed my own utility  [**Rugby**](https://github.com/swiftyfinch/Rugby).

You can use it like that:

```sh
pod install && rugby
```

And all your pods will be moved to cache. It's an easy enough and fast solution.
At the second time,  **Rugby** will compile only changed pods.
Feel free to contact me if you have any issues.